# How to get the maximum value from hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I want to get the maximum value from the hash but i keep getting the first one

```
Crypto_name = ["Bitcoin", "Ethereum", "Project-x", "Fake"]
Crypto_price = ["$5500.6", "$538.9", "$0.25", "$46000.09"]
$crypto = Crypto_name.zip(Crypto_price).to_h

def largest_hash_key
  puts $crypto.max_by{|a,b| b.to_i}
end

largest_hash_key
```

Comment: As a side note: if possible, you should really try and keep the values separate from the currency. It'll make tasks like this a lot easier (and cleaner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the format of each string within crypto_price, you'd need to remove any non-digit character, with those 4 elements, `$` is the one you don't need.

`max` can help you:

```
$crypto.max { |value| value.last.delete('$').to_f }
# "$46000.09"
```

By removing the `$` you get a "convertible" to float number, which you can then compare.

I blindly assume that "$" is the only one character that's not needed among them. But it won't be always this way.

Comment: Perhaps `str_price[1..-1].to_f...`

Comment: I agree if the input is always that way @CarySwoveland, but in cases like `" $5500.6"`, where the first character won't never be the "$" sign.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
$crypto.max_by{|a,b| b.tr('^0-9''.','').to_f}
```

I think this works with any symbols and in any order.